# i want to display Model attribute set in order page

Tags: magento2

I am Using Magento 2.2 , I want to display  product  model attribute   in attribute set on  order page in backend below sku.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want to display a product attribute on the view order page in the admin?

Comment: yes, i want to display  model code of the product in view order page below SKU in admin